# How to insert values into PostConstruct

Tags: spring-boot

I have a H2 in-memory-database with 4 tables.

The table Shop has a connection to Address table.

Now I want to insert some values in my PostConstruct method.

So do my table definitions look like:

Shop:

```
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 2, max = 50)
@Column(name ="name")
private String name;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name ="address")
private Address address;

@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "shop_products")
private List<Product> products;
```

Address

```
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 2, max = 50)
@Column(name ="address", unique = true)
private String address;
```

Product

```
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 2, max = 50)
@Column(name ="name", unique = true)
private String name;

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 2, max = 50)
@Column(name ="manufacturer")
private String manufacturer;

@NotNull
@Column(name ="currentPrice")
private BigDecimal currentPrice;
```

And these are my Service classes with the PostConsutrct method:

Address

```
@PostConstruct
public void initDb() {
    Address address1 = Address.builder().address(AddressEnum.BURGENLAND.toString()).build();
    Address address2 = Address.builder().address(AddressEnum.WIEN.toString()).build();
    Address address3 = Address.builder().address(AddressEnum.TIROL.toString()).build();
    addressRepository.saveAll(List.of(address1, address2, address3));
}
```

Product

```
@PostConstruct
public void initDb() {
    Product product1 = Product.builder().name(ProductEnum.HAMMER.toString()).currentPrice(new BigDecimal(10)).manufacturer("Makita").build();
    Product product2 = Product.builder().name(ProductEnum.KNIFE.toString()).currentPrice(new BigDecimal(20)).manufacturer("Bosch").build();
    Product product3 = Product.builder().name(ProductEnum.NAIL.toString()).currentPrice(new BigDecimal(30)).manufacturer("Hilti").build();
    productRepository.saveAll(List.of(product1, product2, product3));
}
```

Shop

```
@PostConstruct
public void initDb() {
    Shop shop1 = Shop.builder().name("Shop 1").address(new Address(AddressEnum.BURGENLAND.toString())).build();
    Shop shop2 = Shop.builder().name("Shop 2").address(new Address(AddressEnum.BURGENLAND.toString())).build();
    Shop shop3 = Shop.builder().name("Shop 3").address(new Address(AddressEnum.BURGENLAND.toString())).build();
    shopRepository.saveAll(List.of(shop1, shop2, shop3));
}
```

If I delete the PostConstruct in my ShopService class, it works, but then I do not have any data in my Shop table.

Whereas running my application with the PostConstruct, I always get the following error message:

TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation

The problem is I do not know how to get rid of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

What I did change now was the following:

I added **cascade = CascadeType.ALL** in my Shop model class.

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name ="address")
private Address address;
```

Now, it works.